# flattening a table with SQL

Tags: sql

I'm wondering if there is anyway to break a column that has multiple values into separate columns. Here's an example of what I want to do:
Assume I have table 1 as follows:

```
 Team | Value_descriptor| Value 
 Team1| Coach           | McGuire 
 Team1| Manager         | Thompson 
 Team1| City            | Detroit
 Team2| Coach           | Johnson
 Team2| Manager         | Stevenson 
 Team2| City            | LA
```

And I'd like to produce a table as follows:

```
 Team | Coach   | Manager | City 
 Team1| McGuire | Thompson| Detroit 
 Team2| Johnson | Stevenson| LA 
 ...
```

Assume that I will make the second table first. Is there a query that can return the values in the second table from the first table?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Some products have functionality that may be useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it that should work with any database using a `case` expression inside an aggregate.

```
select t1.Team,
       max(case when t1.Value_Descriptor = 'Coach' then t1.Value end) as Coach,
       max(case when t1.Value_Descriptor = 'Manager' then t1.Value end) as Manager,
       max(case when t1.Value_Descriptor = 'City' then t1.Value end) as City
  from table1 t1
 group by t1.Team
```

Alternatively, your database may offer some specific syntax to do the pivoting for you.

Comment: This will work if there aren't plural coach's in the database for a team.

Comment: @Sir Troll: I think it's a safe assumption.  Otherwise, OP's data wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer mit **PIVOT** tested in Oracle DB

```
 select * from tst
 pivot (max(Value)   for (Value_descriptor) in (
 'City' as "CITY",
 'Manager' as "MANAGER",
 'Coach' as "COACH"))
 ;
```

.

```
 TEAM            CITY            MANAGER         COACH         
 --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
 Team2           LA              Stevenson       Johnson         
 Team1           Detroit         Thompson        McGuire
```

Note that the above query, in case there are more values for a specific *value_descriptor* selects the MAX value (alphabetically).

If you want to show all values concatenated replace the aggregate function with *listagg*

```
 pivot (listagg(Value,', ') within  group (order by value)  for (Value_descriptor) in (
```